# Highmaps limit zoom range breaks zooming out

Tags: ajax, highcharts, zooming, highmaps

I am using Highmaps and I limit the zoom range by setting the minRange property in the xAxis property.

This limits the zoom in factor as expected, but when zooming in too much, it does not let you zoom out again until you drag the map. To be more precise, it lets you zoom out until the x-axis is completely visible, but if your viewport is too wide to display the whole y-range of the map at this particular zoom step, you only get a horizontal stripe.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // Initiate the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

            title : {
                text : 'Zoom in on country by double click'
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 1,
                max: 1000,
                type: 'logarithmic'
            },

            xAxis: {
                minRange: 5000 // <- prevent zooming in too much
            },

            series : [{
                data : data,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                name: 'Population density',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: '#BADA55'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '/km²'
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

You can see a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/b9d0ry3t/

This is a standard Highmaps demo, where I simply added the minRange on the xAxis, nothing else.

Comment: I can zoom-in only twice ( `[+]` button). Then using `[-]` button works perfectly fine. Could you provide detailed description? Like in steps, or something similar.

Comment: To see the problem, you first have to drag the window, so that the map container is wider than the map itself and you have blank spaces to the left and to the right of the map. Then you zoom in with the mouse using the mouse wheel until you can't zoom in any further. If you zoom back now, the zooming stops when the maps x-range fills the window, although you would expect the map to zoom out further to the original position it was in. After dragging the map, you can zoom out to the original position again.

Comment: Honestly, I can not reproduce, maybe browser limited issue? Anyway, It sounds rather like problem with lib, have you contacted with support (email) directly?

Comment: This and many other problems have been fixed with the most recent Highmaps update (Feb. 2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This and many other problems have been fixed with the most recent Highmaps update (Feb. 2015).